# Configure/Override EU Cookie Compliance

Tags: 8, configuration

I've installed eu_cookie_complience module (eu_cookie_compliance 8.x-1.9). The documentation is nearly non-existent, but as much as this module is used, I'm hoping to find someone that has solved these issues.

1. The big one: how does one set the `eu_only` parameter to true? Crazy, but there does not seem to be any option in the Admin panel. I could hack the contrib yaml or worse the module and force things. But that's a bad idea.
2. How can I hook into or override eu_cookie_compliance and specify my own IP lookup. Though it isn't documented, apparently there are three ways to check to see if the user is EU (the smart_ip module, the geoip module, or geoip_country_code_by_name())  We already use IPSTACK and I want to leverage that.

Answer (score 3):

1. The settings form is [hard-wired to only display](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/eu-cookie-compliance/-/blob/5ea1a23bf9d3606da7392dfca8481206a2fc7a27/src/Form/EuCookieComplianceConfigForm.php#L739) the config field on the form if one of the following is installed: the [Smart IP](https://www.drupal.org/project/smart_ip) module, [GeoAPI](https://www.drupal.org/project/geoip) module, or the PHP `geoip` extension. Outside that you'll have to bypass the config form; if you're version controlling your config, make the change in the `eu_cookie_compliance.settings.yml` file; or use `drush cset` to make the change directly.
2. The hooks are documented in [`eu_cookie_compliance.api.php`](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/eu-cookie-compliance/-/blob/8.x-1.x/eu_cookie_compliance.api.php). You're wanting to use `hook_eu_cookie_compliance_geoip_match_alter()` that lets you alter the results from the [`eu_cookie_compliance_user_in_eu()`](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/eu-cookie-compliance/-/blob/8.x-1.x/eu_cookie_compliance.module#L569) function. The parameter `$geoip_match` is a keyed-array with `country` & `in_eu` keys that drive the logic.